# Azure Data Factory restart individual cluster

Tags: azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

Problem:- Restarting a cluster while it fails, restarts all the clusters in Databricks workspace. While I want only the failed cluster to start.

I am trying to restart the failed cluster through the data factory. For this, I created a web activity with the following URL: https://adb-****************.2.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/restart

Any help is appreciated !!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To restart the individual cluster you need to add the body with `cluster_id` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#--restart)):

```json
{
  "cluster_id": "<cluster-id>"
}
```